# CanCan - How to setup a modeless Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I have a User Model, with a admin boolean field. I then have an Admin Controller which I want CanCan On.

How do I add CanCan to the Admin Controller as there is not Admin Model?

I've tried:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :admin, :through => :user


class Ability
   include CanCan::Ability
   def initialize
         ....
         can :manage, Admin if current_user.admin == TRUE
         ....
```

But that errors with "Access denied on nil"

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: sorry, `== TRUE`? Is `TRUE` a constant in your app?

Comment: Also: where does the `through` option come from for `load_and_authorize_resource`?

Comment: True is not a constant, it's a boolean, is that not valid?

Comment: RE: through option that's a part of CanCan no? https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/nested-resources

Comment: @AnApprentice: True, TRUE and true are all very, very different.

Comment: @Ryan: Fun fact: you can do `TRUE = false` in Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have access to the 'current_user' method in your ability class? I wouldn't think you would have.

For what I remember when using CanCan you could have this in your Ability class:

```
def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new #guest user.
...
end
```

And the user would be the current user, I expect. And I guess that should work.

You can also take a look at this page: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Non-RESTful-Controllers of the CanCan wiki. It's not exactly the same issue, but as it covers a special case (Non-RESTful-Controllers) it might give you some hints about how to do what you want to do.

Cheers